# Can I use John the Ripper to brute-force a password-protected flash drive?

Tags: brute-force

I have a password-protected flash drive. The input window allows unlimited password attempts, but this form is not an encrypted file.

Can I use John the Ripper to bruteforce the password?

Comment: What do you mean by "*this form is not an encrypted file*"?

Comment: JtR is an 'offline' password cracker. You're looking for an "online" cracker (i.e. Hydra, Medusa, etc.) that supports attacks on the file system access. Need more info to make further recommendations like @techraf said.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the online crackers you have mentioned, however, those were designed for attacking some network protocol. Forgive me if I did not understand it right. Would you mind to talk a little bit about how those online attackers can solve the problems I mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: I mentioned the form is not an encrypted file because there is only a window that accepts the password input. I know lots of the bruteforce software works with a file or a hash, that's why I specifically mentioned that. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

No. John the Ripper is designed to look at a hash and compare it to common password hashes, salted or unsalted. It doesn't directly input values into a box, and it uses GPU acceleration when available to reduce processing time. Unless you can find the hash for the password on the flash drive, this tool is completely worthless for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with you. Is there any software in your mind could possible perform this job? I locked some old lab notes in the flash drive, but I cannot access it now.